# Do I bother with MVVM when my Model and ViewModel are exactly the same? WP 8.1

Tags: c#, mvvm, windows-phone-8.1

I am working on a Windows Phone 8.1 (non SL) application. It is a quiz game about fruits and veg aimed at children. Here is my entire model:

```
namespace FruityLogic.Models
{
    public class Quiz
    {
        public int lives { get; set; }
        public Question Question { get; set; }
        public List<Feg> Feges { get; set; } // Feg meaning Fruit and Veg ;)
        public List<int> IdsOfDoneFeges { get; set; }

        public Quiz()
        {
            LoadData();
            lives = 3;
            IdsOfDoneFeges = new List<int>();
            Question = new Question()
            {
                Feg = Feges[0],
                OptionFeges = new List<Feg>()
                {
                    Feges[1],
                    Feges[2],
                    Feges[0]
                }
            };
        }

        public void LoadData()
        {
            Feges = new List<Feg>()
            {
                new Feg() { Id = 0, Name = "Banana", Image = "../assets/banana.jpg"},
                new Feg() { Id = 1, Name = "Orange", Image = "../assets/orange.jpg"},
                new Feg() { Id = 2, Name = "Apple", Image = "../assets/apple.jpg"},
                new Feg() { Id = 3, Name = "Cherry", Image = "../assets/cherry.jpg"},
                new Feg() { Id = 4, Name = "watermelon", Image = "../assets/watermelon.jpg"},
                new Feg() { Id = 5, Name = "Lettuce", Image = "../assets/lettuce.jpg"},
            };
        }
    }
}
```

The quiz would should a picture of a fruit or a veg on screen, and the user would select the correct name for the shown fruit / veg.

I am struggling with the MVVM aspect. I read [this tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/gg521153(v=vs.105).aspx), but it doesn't really apply to me, or at least I can't make it relate!

My Model and ViewModel are exactly the same as far as I can see. Do I bother creating a ViewModel?

Also, how can I inform my View, that a Question has changed, so that it binds to the next question? Do I implemented `INotifyPropertyChanged` on the `Question` class and fire it for every single property of the Question? Or would just one property suffice? Also, if I do that, there is no `ObservableObject<>` to be wrapped around the Question in my `Quiz` class, how would the Quiz know that Question has changed?

As you can tell, I'm confused by all of this, and would greatly appreciate some clarification.

Comment: Model does all logic. ViewModel does all logic related to cooperate with possible View, which want to display data and do something with them. ViewModel should **not** itself add or manipulate with data, those actions are done in Model and ViewModel simply forward calls. You create questions in the ViewModel. You shouldn't. Serialization of questions, checking for correct answer - that's what Model should do.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> My Model and ViewModel are exactly the same as far as I can see. Do I bother creating a ViewModel?

Yes. You need a ViewModel to databind the View to. The question is whether you need a separate Model. That depends on what else you do with it, like storing in a Db or file. But a separate Model is usually a good idea.

And none of your Model properties is implementing INotifyPropertyChanged, that's something to address, for instance by replicating them in the VM with INPC.

> Also, how can I inform my View, that a Question has changed, so that it binds to the next question?

By adding a SelectedQuestion property. That is a task for a VM. 'Selected' is usually not a meaningful concept for a Model.

In summary, the ViewModel should do the 'Presentation Logic', the Model the 'Bussines Logic'.

A ViewModel can be pretty simple, by forwarding the entire Model class as a single property. And then add SelectedSomething etc.

I always liked [this picture](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32224997/60761), but others find it too complicated.

Comment: Loved the point about the `SelectedQuestion` property. Still not clear on where to implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged`. All my [code is here](https://github.com/Ciwan1859/FruitySmart) as I'm simply learning at the moment.

Comment: When one has `INotifyPropertyChanged` implemented, does one **always** need it coupled with `IObsersvable`? Or is it simply enough to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` and the view would update on change

Comment: IObservable is not needed in MVVM. But `ObservableCollection<>`s are to be used instead of `List<>`.

Comment: Can you link me to an example where a single Object (e.g. my Question) (not a collection of objects) is being bound?

Comment: ObservableCollection will inform the ListView of any items added or removed from it. 
You implement the INPC interface in the ViewModel and the raise the OnPropertyChanged in the property setter like this:

`public string Name
{
get {return _name;}
set {_name = value; OnPropertyChanges(....); }
}`

Comment: I love the image. I wish I had that for reference when I was learning how to implement MVVM.