# Mvvm model ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

It can be named MVVM model or not? Because View interacts with DataModel through
ViewModelData. Does View should interact only with ViewModelData? I did read somewhere that right MVVM model should implement INotify in ViewModel not in Model. Is it right?

```
namespace WpfApplication135
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new ViewModelData();
    }
}
public class ViewModelData
{
    public DataModel DM { get; set; }
    public ViewModelData()
    {
        DM = new DataModel();
    }
}
public class DataModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public int label;
    public int Label
    {
        get
        {
            return label;
        }

        set
        {
            label = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Label");
        }
    }
    public DataModel()
    {
        Action Update = new Action(Run);
        IAsyncResult result = Update.BeginInvoke(null, null);
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void RaisePropertyChanged(string info)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
    }
    public void Run()
    {
        int i=0;
        while(true)
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
            Label = ++i;
        }
    }
}
}
```

xaml

```
    <Grid>
    <Label Content="{Binding DM.Label}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>

</Grid>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The initial thought for MVVM was indeed that the View should not know (not depend on) the Model.

In practice this meant re-implementing all those Model properties in the ViewModel (see the light-yellow box in the picture below), a lot of work.  And extra painful when your Model can easily implement INPC, for example when it is generated from a database schema. Entity Framework in database-first mode lets you inject the INPC code through the T4 templates.

The consensus quickly became that it is OK to forward a `ViewModel.Model` property and bind to that, just like your `DM` property. See the light-blue box in the picture.

The issue is visualized well in this picture, note the large number of arrows in the top right corner. They depict the various solutions for databinding and you can use any combination of them.

[image: WPF LOB Apllication Layers - MVVM]

Comment: In the picture above, the xaml is binding to both the ViewModel and the Model at the same time, or are these bindings exclusive of one another?  The diagram doesn't specify.  If they can both be bound at the same time, how do you achieve this?

Comment: I don't see the question I just asked anywhere.  I know you can bind to the ViewModel and I know you can bind to the Model, what I don't know how to bind to both at the same time because I always set BindingContext in the code-behind and there is no way that I know of to set BindingContext to two different sources at the same time.  I should probably ask this in another post.

Answer (score 0):

One point of MVVM is that your view should not know your data model and vice versa. That's why there is a ViewModel. Right now, your ViewModel is wasted code. It does nothing.

You may want to read up on MVVM a bit more, because explaining it is way too broad for the Q&A format here.

Comment: Also the notion of property change notification isn't specific to the view/view-model relationship, there are plenty of cases where it helps for the model to support IPCN as well. Adding it to your DAL entities automatically can be achieved by either injecting a proxy into your repositories at runtime (see [Castle Dynamic Proxy](http://goo.gl/DQWs2P)) or modifying the IL itself with a post-processing step at compile time (see [Fody](http://goo.gl/sesOcN)).