# The name 'Set' does not exist in the current context. In my model class

Tags: c#, uwp, template10

I get the error The name 'Set' does not exist in the current context in my model class.

I generate the property from T10_Property snippet.

Here are the source code.

```
using PropertyChanged;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Template10.Mvvm;
using Template10.Services.NavigationService;
using Template10.Utils;
using Windows.UI;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;

namespace Models
{
    [ImplementPropertyChanged]
    public class WiFiAccessPoint
    {
        string _SSID = default(string);
        public string SSID { get { return _SSID; } set { Set(ref _SSID, value); } }

    }
}
```

Comment: Questions should be self-contained. Add the relevant code (and not all 100+ lines, if there are that many).

Comment: The `Set(ref ..., ...)` method comes from the BindableBase class in the T10 framework.

Comment: It is clear you're calling a method named `Set` in the property setter but this method is not defined in your class. Did you forget to inherit from a class that implements this method? Or did you simply forget to implement this method?

Comment: It is debatable if you should make your Model class do INPC or that you should find another way. There are many options, have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32224997/60761).

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen  I did not forget to inherit from a class. I simply didn't know that I should. I initially thought that I'm missing a using reference.

Comment: @HenkHolterman BindableBase solves the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The reason you are getting this is due to the inherited base class you **aren't** using in this case which would be `ViewModelBase` for a viewmodel or `BindableBase` for a model or `ValidatableModelBase` for a validation required model with the `Template10.Validation` library.  Instead you are using Fody? (uses AUTO Properties btw

```
[ImplementPropertyChanged]
public class SomeViewModel{
   public bool SomeBoolProperty {get;set;} // no backers required..
}
```

) or some injectable propertychange attribute system, which doesn't know about `Set()`.  Maybe time to read the manual for the Attribute based injector?

Therefore you will not have access to `Set()`.

Comment: Thanks. Bindablebase solves the problem. I don't understand whats the problem with Fody.PropertyChanged. Whats the recommended way to do things here? Should I drop Fody.PropertyChanged and use T10 BindableBase?  Or vice versa?

Comment: its a personal choice to use it nothing wrong there, but understand before using.  Set comes from the T10_property which is part of the BindableBase.  Fody won't have it.  secondly fody if you look under the hood injects the INPC into the model for you...

Answer (score 2):

If you did this

```
[ImplementPropertyChanged]
public class WiFiAccessPoint: ViewModelBase
{
    string _SSID = default(string);
    public string SSID { get { return _SSID; } set { Set(ref _SSID, value); } }

}
```

It would work. But you are weaving IL, so you better test.