# UWP Data-Binding not working with ViewModel

Tags: mvvm, data-binding, uwp, inotifypropertychanged, uwp-xaml

Fairly new to UWP and MVVM I came across a problem which might seem obvious to many of you.

In my project I have 3 folders named `Views`, `ViewModels` and `Models` which include some files as seen in the image bellow:

`Can't upload image yet (reputation):`

https://i.stack.imgur.com/YcKus.png

> > **The problem:**
> >     I am trying to implement MVVM. I have searched hours for articles and videos but it seems I am always missing something. I have some bindings in the `LoginPage.xaml` which I then modify in a class inside `Models/LoginPageModel.cs`. I have an `INotifyPropertyChanged` class in my LoginPageViewModel.cs where every time a property changes in my `LoginPageModel.cs` I want the `INotifyPropertyChanged` class to trigger which will then change the property in the `LoginPage.xaml` View. Below I have the content of those files.

**This is a sample of my `LoginPageModel.cs` code:**

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;

namespace App_Name.Models
{
    class LoginPageModel
    {
        private NotifyChanges notify;

        public async void LogIn()
        {
            if (something is true)
                notify.LoginUIVisibility = Visibility.Visible;
        }
    }
}
```

**This is my `LoginPageViewModel.cs`:**

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;

namespace App_Name.ViewModels
{
    public class NotifyChanges : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        private Visibility loginUIVisibility = Visibility.Collapsed;

        public Visibility LoginUIVisibility
        {
            get
            {
                return loginUIVisibility;
            }

            set
            {
                if (value != loginUIVisibility)
                {
                    loginUIVisibility = value;
                    NotifyPropertyChanged("LoginUIVisibility");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Here is an example of `LoginPage.xaml`:**

```
<Page
    x:Class="App_Name.LoginPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:App_Name"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:vm="using:App_Name.ViewModels"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Page.DataContext>
        <vm:NotifyChanges/>
    </Page.DataContext>

    <StackPanel Visibility="{Binding LoginUIVisibility}">
```

**Here is my `LoginPage.xaml.cs`:**

```
namespace App_Name
{
    public sealed partial class LoginPage : Page
    {
        private LoginPageModel login;
        public LoginPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            login.LogIn();
        }
    }
}
```

> I don't know why this is not working. Bindings used not to work, but now at runtime it gives me an unhandled exception and I think it has to do with not assigning any value to the  `private NotifyChanges notify` and `private LoginPageModel login` objects, but I don't know what. Thanks everyone for your time in advance!

*Please if you need clarifications for my question just write a comment. Thank you!*

Comment: basically you are creating new notifyChanges object (what a name for a ViewModel...) and set your property within it, why do you expect the UI to change if is has different instance of this class set as DataContext?

Comment: So this goes into my initial page constructor instead of the XAML ?

And how do I reference it in the ViewModel file ?

Comment: that's one of the possible ways to do that, in construtor (in xaml.cs file) create instance of the ViewModel, keep reference to it and set it as DataContext, now when you will be playing with properties of this referenced object the UI should change trough binding

Comment: If everything was in the same file it would work. My problem is that DataContext = new NotifyChanges(); happens in my XAML.cs file and the NotifyChanges() class and the class where I modifie those properties are in a different file. Different file: two classes on is NotifyChanges and the other Is where the modification happens. Again, How do I reference those properties from NotifyChanges class to the class above in the same file WITHOUT making a new instance ? Thank you :)

Comment: DataContext = new NotifyChanges(); in contructor xaml.cs file of mysterious control you did't named in samples above, then in your different object you need to have reference to either ViewModel (you need to just changed its property) or your control(xaml.cs) instance - if so get its DataContext (eg. var viewModel = sampleControl.DataContext as NotifyChanges;) and play with its property, hint: read about View first and ViewModel first approaches in MVVM

Comment: In your binding try to bind the data context in two way mode. Something like this. <StackPanel Visibility="{Binding LoginUIVisibility,Mode=TwoWay}">

Comment: Have you tried to follow [some tutorials](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/johnshews_blog/2015/09/09/a-minimal-mvvm-uwp-app/)?

Comment: Yes I have tried and read my tutorials and solutions but I am missing a key piece in the puzzle. I have achieved everything on my own (self-learner), so that's why I am asking for help here.

I have edited the full post. If you have the time please read from the beginning and try to provide an answer. Thank you :)

Comment: Even when you fix the bindings, your architecture is still very wrong. The Model should not depend on the ViewModel. Your ViewModel should (preferably) not use UI types like Visibility. And the name should match that of the filename.

Comment: And with the Model field in the View (code behind) you have created a dependency circle, that should be removed.

Comment: Since you tagged UWP, have a good look at the Template10 (see Tools, Extensions and Updates) Minimal template. It doesn't have a Model but that's OK for now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I am trying to implement MVVM.

And you're not getting it right yet. Forget about the Bindings for a moment, let's focus on the architecture.

Going down the acronym, you need

- a Model. It supports your business logic and usually is defined by your backend (database). It should not depend on (be aware of) the Views or ViewModels. A lightweight UWP app could do without a Model layer.
- a View. This is the XAML part that we like to keep as simple as possible, a.o. reasons because it's hardest to test.
- a ViewModel. It's purpose is to serve the View. It should contain properties and commands the View can directly bind to. It does as much conversion and aggregation as possible to keep the View light.  It usually relies on (0 or more) Models or Services.

Given this, it is not the case that you should always have 1 Model for 1 ViewModel. A ViewModel could use multiple Models, or none.

It is clear that your `LoginPageModel.Login()` is in the wrong place. `Login()` should be a method (Command) on your ViewModel.

Your story should go like this:

1. I want a LoginView
2. So I need to support it with a LoginViewModel, implementing INPC
3. The ViewModel probably needs to use a LoginService or a UserModel. But it would only need a Model instance after a successful login.  A LoginModel doesn't sound right.

Have a look at [Template10](https://github.com/Windows-XAML/Template10/wiki) to get started with View, ViewModel and a  thread-safe BindableBase.

You could also look a the picture [over here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32224997/60761) for a full (over the top maybe) layout of MVVM.

Answer (score 0):

> And here is the call for change in the main class:
>
> `NotifyChanges notifyChanges = new NotifyChanges();`
>
> `notifyChanges.LoginUIVisibility = Visibility.Visible;`

You have instantiated `notifyChanges` in the `XAML` file by adding  `<vm:NotifyChanges/>`. And add a binding to StackPanel by using `<StackPanel Visibility="{Binding LoginUIVisibility}">`. But you created a new `notifyChanges`, and you did not bind the new `notifyChanges` to `StackPanel`. So it won't work. You could initialize `viewModel` just like following code.

**MainPage**

```
private LoginViewModel viewModel;

public MainPage()
 {
     this.InitializeComponent();
     viewModel = this.DataContext as LoginViewModel;
 }

 private void showDetail_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
     viewModel.LoginUIVisibility = Visibility.Visible;
 }
```

**MainPage.xaml**

```
<Page.DataContext>
    <vm:LoginViewModel />
</Page.DataContext>
<StackPanel Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Button x:Name="loginButon" Content="Login" Visibility="{Binding LoginUIVisibility}" />
    <Button x:Name="showDetail" Content="Show" Click="showDetail_Click" />
</StackPanel>
```