# WPF MVVM Model how to get data

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Recently, I'm learning MVVM design pattern!

In my way, I write the database function in the model, and let the viewmodel to call the database function in the model, then the viewmodel get database data and set to the viewmodel notfiypropertychanged. This is my way that I currently use!

There are some question confused me about model,
I read many article that told me model just a contain data and not more business logic, and here is my question, if model just a data container and I need to let my viewmodel to call the database then get data and set to the model, I think this way is very strange and the viewmodel code is make heavy in it. Is anybody have another method to do it? Thank you!

Comment: Are you using `.NET Core`?

Comment: I don't have a lot of time right now but see if this [Microsoft Document](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg405484(v=pandp.40).aspx)  helps.

Comment: I don't know where you got the *"model just a contain data and not more business logic"* from, but for me, business logic is part of the model. However, I observe a tendency of business logic leaking into the viewmodel for my projects and I can't say whether that's a bad thing in general.

Comment: The Prism link from @aaronR is not the lightest material. The [picture here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32224997/60761) might help a little, but it's ambitious too.

Comment: Some people refer to the business logic classes of their application as the Model! Other people refer to the data classes used to communicate with business logic (e.g., argument and return value types) as Models! I'm of the latter! I also prefer to end all my sentences with an exclamation point!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The Model:**

> "model just a contain data and not more business logic"

A model is a class which describe an entity within your domain logic. What is a domain? Starbuck's domain is coffee beverages and employees (among others), Ford's domain is cars, assembly lines, and employees. NYTimes's domain is articles, issues, supply routes, subscribers, etc, etc.

A model contains data AND logic. You can have multiple models to describe your domain.

You can place your data calls in your model, but it's more common to have helper classes, data access layers (DAL), keeping all your database calls in one place, and not spread them around.

**The ViewModel:**

The viewmodel sits between your domain model and your view. It's a class which expose properties of the model and represents the state of the view. The viewmodel may only exposes a subset of all the properties in the model that the UI needs to display, but it could also add properties of its own, for example; is the user in edit mode? have changes been made that needs saving? etc. The selling point with MVVM is that the UI binds to these properties on the viewmodel which is a mechanism to keep the UI up to date with changes, and this extra layer of abstraction conveniently decouples the view to any logic in your model making it more robust for code changes in either direction and testable. There's more to say on this topic, but I'll leave it to you to read on up it.

There are many good resources and info on the MVVM pattern; from blogs [Model-View-ViewModel (MVVM) Explained](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/100175/Model-View-ViewModel-MVVM-Explained), to Microsoft [The MVVM Pattern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh848246.aspx) and here on SO.

If you prefer videos, Pluralsight have good video tutorials on the MVVM pattern 
[Practical MVVM](https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/practical-mvvm/description) and [WPF MVVM In Depths](https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/wpf-mvvm-in-depth/table-of-contents). They have a free 30-day trial.

> "just a data container"

Such classes that only hold data to be passed around are often called Data Transfer Objects (DTO). It's common to keep them small and return collections of these from fetch database data method calls.

Answer (score 0):

I've done some research in this and also found it quite confusing. First thing I like to point out is that code-patterns are abstract. Meaning that you have loads of different way to implement it / tweak it.

What most people have told me is that in "real-life" applications you usually have layers of services.

One of these services is where you get data from a database.

The Model job (in my opinion) is to give the developer knowledge about the database data and structure. One Model to one database-tabel.
It also helps in checking if the data is correct (Format checking, Type of data and so on) before sending it to the DB.

There isn't a clear answer on how to use model. I've seen loads of different implementations, and they all have been implemented for specific tasks.

Yes it might come out that some ViewModels become heavy-loaded with code and functions to perform, but then it might not be because of the code-pattern. It can be because of poor structure in code. At my work right now I've found a ViewModel that contained over 3000 lines of code (Which is WAY to much). This could easily be seperated into atleast 3 different ViewModels and Views, but as I said, poor code structure causes problem.

One thing I recommend for you to read up on is

- IoC - Inversion of Control
- DoP - Dependency inversion principle
- DI - Dependency Injection

Hope this helps in someway explaining your question.

Answer (score 0):

> I read many article that told me model just a contain data and not more business logic

A model may be represented by a service, a database access layer or a business layer so there is nothing wrong with your current approach. The business logic does belong to the model.

But sometimes people tend to refer to a "child" type as a model. For example, if your view model exposes a `List<Item>` property, the `Item` class may considered to be a model. Perhaps your confusion comes from this.

This kind of classes (`Item`) typically implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface to provide change notifications and are effectively rather just "nested" view models that don't contain any business logic though.

Hope that makes sense.