# how to convert a list of models to an collection of modelVM-s?

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, mvvm

I'm relatively new to MVVM and entity framework.

Up until now, I made my entity models implement INotifyPorpertyChanged interface, then in the WindowVM class I populated an ObservableCollection with the model objects loaded from a DB with a Linq query, and made my databindings in xaml to this list (or to the selected item on a listbox with itemsource set to this Collection).

But i read on several sites and blogs that this is a bad practice, as I'm exposing my model directly to the view, and i have to pollute my models with logic directly related to the view(for example an IsSelected property set to [Not Mapped]).

As I read, a better approach would be, to create a ViewModel classes warping the model classes.

But how should I convert a list of models(returned by a linq query) to an collection of modelVM-s?

Comment: For `BlahModel`, write a `BlahViewModel` class. Give `BlahViewModel` a constructor `BlahViewModel(BlahModel model)` -- make the constructor do whatever it needs to. Give the parent viewmodel a public property `ObservableCollection<BlahViewModel> Blahs {/*INPC stuff*/}`. Then in the parent viewmodel, `Blahs = new ObservableCollection<BlahViewModel>(blahModelQuery.Select(m => new BlahViewModel(m)));`

Comment: You should write ViewModels for _Views_, not for Models.  SelectedItem belongs to a VM, it has no place in a M. But on Occasion, if you want to exactly show a Model, just pass it through.

Comment: +1 @HenkHolterman A View needs data, and its needs define the ViewModel.  A ViewModel will have data from multiple Model Entities, along with data not from any Model Entity that manage the current state of the user's interaction with the application (eg an IsSelected property).

Comment: You may want to look at the picture [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32224997/60761)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

@EdPlunkett thanx! how didn't I think of this? (I'm feeling so dumb right now)

only a slight modification:

```
Blahs = new ObservableCollection<BlahViewModel>(
                  blahModelQuery.Select(m => new BlahViewModel(m))
        );
```

this will throw an System.NotSupportedException:

"Only parameterless constructors and initializers are supported in LINQ to Entities."

```
Blahs = new ObservableCollection<BlahViewModel>(
                  blahModelQuery.Select(m => new BlahViewModel(){model = m})
        );
```